# Properly use Return Keyword

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to programming and I have a question. I want to get a list of computers on the network, I have done this successfully, then I have been able to get how many computers there are by using .Count()...The issue is, I have several places in my full code where I would like to reference that number, and everytime I try to use c, it tells me that variable doesn't exist in its context. I tried to make my own public method but then it asks me to put in a proper return, and after searching. I still can't figure it out.. Can anyone point me in the correct direction? Thank you.

```
public void ComputersOnNetwork()
{
   List<string> list = new List<string>();
   using (DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT:"))
   {
       foreach (DirectoryEntry computer in computers.Children)
       {
           if ((computer.Name != "Schema"))
           {
               list.Add(computer.Name);
           }
       }

       foreach (string s in list)
       {
          int c = list.Count();
          return c;
       }
```

Comment: Please post the code you're working with.

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of the code taht you have tried?

Comment: Why using `foreach`when you don't really iterate over the elements of the list? Also, why saving to a list when you only need count?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are missing  the `return` statement in your method. You need to have a return type (probably integer type in this case as your returning the number of computers)

```
public int ComputersOnNetwork()
{        
  List<string> list = new List<string>();
  using (DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT:"))
  {
       foreach (DirectoryEntry computer in computers.Children)
       {
          if ((computer.Name != "Schema"))
          {
             list.Add(computer.Name);
          }
       }
  }
  return list.Count;     
}
```

Now you can call this wherever you want like this

```
int totalInThisCase=ComputersOnNetwork();
```

Comment: Sorry for not having the code there right away.. Still getting use to how to navigate the site :)

Comment: @CoreyDeising: I updated my answer based on the update on your question.

Comment: `totalItems.Count` should be `list.Count`

Comment: @climbage: Yes. I was using a variable with that name when i posted first. Thanks. Corrected it now.

Comment: @Shyju Haha yep, I saw it go down

Comment: OOOh I was pretty clue I think, I just had my return in the wrong spot I think. along with getting rid of the extra int C... You guys are awesome.. haha thank you!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You must have a return type, and you should use a count variable instead of adding to a list and then returning the count (also, why did you iterate over the list like that? You didn't need to do that).

Always read your code logically and see if the actions are logically performed correctly.

```
public int ComputersOnNetwork()
{
    int count = 0;

    using (DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT:"))
    {
        foreach (DirectoryEntry computer in root.Children)
        {
            if ((computer.Name != "Schema"))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

    return count;
}
```

Or you can use LINQ to have a short version:

```
public int ComputersOnNetwork()
{
    using (var root = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT:"))
    {
        return root.Children.Cast<DirectoryEntry>().Count(x => x.Name != "Schema");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to that final loop - if list contains all of the computers then this should do it:

```
  public void ComputersOnNetwork()
  {
       List<string> list = new List<string>();
       using (DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT:"))
       {
           foreach (DirectoryEntry computer in computers.Children)
           {
               if ((computer.Name != "Schema"))
               {
                   list.Add(computer.Name);
               }
           }
       }

      return list.Count();
  }
```

Return statements will stop the execution of a function as soon as you hit them, so your final for loop would only have run once.

Even without the return statement you would have had problems because `c` was declared within the loop and it would have gone out of **scope**, which is why you weren't able to reference it later on in your code. You need to be careful about declaring variables inside loops, they'll get re-defined on each iteration and although your code may compile it can be tricky to trace such bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the foreach loop at the end. You're never using the variable "s" so it's wasted processing.

To get what you want change your method to retun an int instead of void and then return list.Count at the end.

```
public int ComputersOnNetwork()
{
   List<string> list = new List<string>();
   using (DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT:"))
   {
       foreach (DirectoryEntry computer in computers.Children)
       {
           if ((computer.Name != "Schema"))
           {
               list.Add(computer.Name);
           }
       }

       int c = list.Count;
       return c;
   }
}
```

You'd then call your method whenever you need the value:

```
Int computerCount = ComputersOnNetwork();
```